# You must specify a value for this required field

Tags: team-sites

I am building a team site. when I try to save the page, I get the following error.

You must specify a value for this required field

I have hidden the following content place holder.But still I get the error.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" />
```

Could you please help me to fix this error?

The whole piece of code is

```
<asp:Panel Visible="false" runat="server" cssclass="hideplaceholder">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSiteName" runat="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderBodyLeftBorder" runat="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderTitleLeftBorder" runat="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderTitleAreaSeparator" runat="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="OSSConsole" runat="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderTitleRightMargin" runat="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat ="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" runat ="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyRightMargin" runat="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBorder" runat="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="WSSDesignConsole" runat="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderMiniConsole" runat="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" />
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server"/>
 </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Why should hiding the placeholder help?

Comment: I am afraid; as I have googled about this issue and found this as a work around. Hence, I am hinding that.

Comment: Thanks Monica. I have tried this. But no use.I am trying to enter some textual content in to a blank home page and trying to save. But it is not allowing me to save due to this error.

Answer (score 1):

Go to list settings and make the Title column setting : Required - No

Comment: Could some one help me with this please?